# Is it possible to run out of unlock tokens on Zombies?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

At some point in Zombies I'm going to want to do a fresh reset. I see people who's levels are triple digits, which I think means they can't prestige further. If that's true and by the time I got to that point I spent all my unlock tokens on GobbleGum and unlocking weapons, would it be impossible to prestige? Should I always have one unlock token spare?